# Ljung-Box test on a out of sample residue with good forecast

Tags: time-series, forecasting, statsmodels

To test the [fbprophet](https://github.com/facebook/prophet) library, I created a very simple synthetic series and generated a model like this:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from fbprophet import Prophet
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idx = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', '2016-05-04', freq='D')
phase = np.pi / 2
len_idx = len(idx)
points = np.arange(0, len_idx)
df = pd.DataFrame({'y': np.sin(points * 2 * np.pi / 30 + phase) + points / 100}, index=idx)
df['ds'] = df.index

mdl = Prophet()
mdl.add_seasonality('monthly', period=30, fourier_order=5)
df_result = mdl.predict(30, 'D')
_ = mdl.model.plot(df_result)
```

[image]

what looks like a very good fit and forecast. I'm now trying to evaluate the forecast using the Ljung-Box statistic:

```
df_train = df.iloc[:100]
df_test = df.iloc[100:]
mdl = Prophet()
mdl.add_seasonality('monthly', period=30, fourier_order=5)
df_forecast = mdl.predict(df_test)
df_forecast.index = df_forecast.ds
residue = df_test.y - df_forecast.yhat
nlags = 20
sm.stats.diagnostic.acorr_ljungbox(residue, nlags)
(array([26.58531982, 37.54004325, 39.75143298, 39.87513462, 39.87724859,
    39.87823833, 39.87841515]),
 array([2.52152459e-07, 7.05152716e-09, 1.20293579e-08, 4.59357440e-08,
    1.58094709e-07, 4.81312117e-07, 1.32806258e-06]))
```

and I get very small values for the p-value, meaning that the null hypothesis cannot be rejected (if I understood the test correctly), so there is still autocorrelated values in the forecast residue. What is the probable cause of this? The residues for this model look like
[image: residues]

Comment: Either a deficient model or a deterministic time series

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that. How a deterministic time series would generate a Ljung-Box test with small p-values?

Answer (score -1):

If there is untreated deterministic structure in the model residuals this inflates the error variance and downwards biases the acg thus downwards biasing the anacronostic Ljung-Box test . Deterministic structure like pulses , seasonal pulses , level/step shifts or local time trends arise quite frequently .

If you post your data I will try and help further.

Comment: Could you explain how this is relevant?  The data were generated as shown in the question.  Perhaps you posted this answer in the wrong place?

Comment: ok if he generated the data ... i didn't  as I don't use r and I was asking him to post it. If he doesn't want to do that nevermind !. his residuals suggest a deficient model or over-parameterized model.

Comment: The OP doesn't use `R` either: this is Python code.  The code and the plot look like enough information to generate the data using any language you like--how about Fortran? :-)

Comment: i don't use python ... and for me to check on "stuff" I like to use the actual data. If he doesn't want to post it he can email it... less work for me |

Comment: Regardless, isn't it clear that none of the things you mention will be relevant to such a dataset?  Take a look at the sizes of the forecast residuals, btw.

Comment: The problem may be as simple as trying to fit a perfect series ... numerical issues can arise yielding bizarre results. Analyzing the data shouldn't be perfunctorily dismissed in order to deconstruct it. There may be other causes for this malformation and with my experience analyzing the actual data can sometimes be (if not always ! ) useful .

Comment: ................................

Comment: Nobody is saying that data analysis lacks value or shouldn't be done.  I'm just suggesting that it's important to read the question and respond to what it asks and to the context in which it is asked.  Your post here is essentially the same as several hundred other responses you have posted--sometimes very helpfully--but it just doesn't seem remotely applicable to this case.

Comment: ok ... I agree .

Comment: I thought that I made clear that the data is synthetic and generated from the expression in the code, but in any case I generated like this: `np.sin(points * 2 * np.pi / 30 + phase) + points / 100`, where `points` is a sequential array.